# Data Mapping Issue

Tags: ios, swift

I am in the process of trying to map data from  an API to my custom class but I get this error in the console "typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil). Not sure why it's showing this when it an array in there; how do I resolve this issues. Error

```
struct News: Codable {
    var status: String?
    var totalResults: Int?
    var articles: [Article]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status = "status"
        case totalResults = "totalResults"
        case articles = "articles"
    }
}

// MARK: - Article
struct Article: Codable {
    var source: Source?
    var author: String?
    var title: String?
    var articleDescription: String?
    var url: String?
    var urlToImage: String?
    var publishedAt: String?
    var content: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case source = "source"
        case author = "author"
        case title = "title"
        case articleDescription = "description"
        case url = "url"
        case urlToImage = "urlToImage"
        case publishedAt = "publishedAt"
        case content = "content"
    }
}

 func getAllCountryNameFrom() {
        AF.request(self.baseURL + self.apiKeyPathCompononent, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil, interceptor: nil).response { (responseData) in
                guard let data = responseData.data else {return}
            do {
                let news = try self.jsonDecoder.decode(News.self, from: data)
                   print(news)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Attach your `data` as `.utf8` string.

Answer (score 1):

1. try this website/tool, https://app.quicktype.io/, it generates a
   model from your Schema
2. you can use https://proxyman.io/ to track your response JSON